# Delay loading of images in slideshow with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, slideshow

I have a fullscreen slideshow that consists of 4 slides, but I do not want to load all images at the same time, so I thought of adding a setTimeout in javascript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
   $('.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span').css("background-image: url(/slides/2.jpg)");
}, 5000);
```

The slideshow consists of 6 elements, each animated in with keyframes.

Slides:

```
    .cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
    background-image: url(/slides/1.jpg) 
    }
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
   background-image: url(/slides/2.jpg);
 animation-delay: 6s;
 }
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
    background-image: url(/slides/3.jpg);
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
    background-image: url(/slides/4.jpg);
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
```

Slideshow:

```
<ul class="cb-slideshow">
            <li><span>Image 01</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 02</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 03</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 04</span></li>
        </ul>
```

Style:

```
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -2;
    list-style: none
}
.cb-slideshow li span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -2;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
}
.cb-slideshow li div {
z-index: 1000;
position: absolute;
bottom: 90px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: right;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-animation: titleAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
-moz-animation: titleAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
-o-animation: titleAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
-ms-animation: titleAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
animation: titleAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
}
.cb-slideshow li div h3 {
    font-size: 160px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    line-height: 120px;
    color: rgba(169,3,41, 0.8);
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
```

But it's not working. Can I even have li:nth-child(2) inside a script? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Delay loading of images in slideshow with setTimeout?

This would be my approach.

**Adjust your HTML, by adding your image src's as attributes i.e. `data-bg-src="/slides/2.jpg"`:**

```
<ul class="cb-slideshow">
    <li> 
        <span style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/1200/800?image=0')">Image 01</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span data-bg-src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800?image=1">Image 02</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span data-bg-src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800?image=2">Image 03</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span data-bg-src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800?image=3">Image 04</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
(function() {
    const bgSrcs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bg-src]');

    for (let i = 0, m = bgSrcs.length; i < m; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            bgSrcs[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bgSrcs[i].dataset.bgSrc + ')';
            // Or in jQuery
            // $(bgSrcs[i]).css('background-image: url(' + bgSrcs[i].dataset.bgSrc + ')');
        }, i * 1000); // Stagger the load
    }
})();
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lawlesss/qyf5hcxa/14/) (Open the console)

I presume this is in an effort to increase performance by lazy loading images. If this is the case, there are far better ways of doing this. Among the many resources out there, this one on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-complete-guide-to-lazy-loading-images/) appears to be the most comprehensive and up-to-date.

**EDIT 1:**

Your CSS is broken too. You'll need to add the following, if your adding the `background-images` to the `<span>`:

```
.cb-slideshow li{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

And remove `opacity: 0;` from `.cb-slideshow li span {}`.

Below is an example of this in action.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but your fiddle doesn't seem to work? 

And the lazyload method would be perfect, but since the images are not being scrolled into viewport, they always load immediately

Comment: @Brian your question was how to add images using a `setTimeout()`, that example fiddle did do that, but since your CSS was broken, the effect was only apparent in the console, I have updated my response with the fixes required to your CSS too.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!
You correctly implemented the setTimout function!!